# Different views for different types of login in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-admin, django-authentication

I am working on a project of online food ordering using Django. 
Problem is I want to create different views according to the user that is customer, restaurant management and delivery person. 
On the same platform they should view different pages as per the credentials. 
How to create different views according to the login credentials in Django? and How to check which category they belongs to like customer... what should I stores in models to check the category and assign view accordingly?

Comment: you can add one field which will be choiceField let's call it user_type, and based on user type you can redirect user to required page

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for a way to implement multiple user types. Vitor has an excellent tutorial on his blog over here: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/01/18/how-to-implement-multiple-user-types-with-django.html

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following :

1. Add some categorization on your users. It can be done with a [ChoiceField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/fields/#choicefield) (or even more granular with subclasses,...)
2. In your views, there is a `request` variable from which you can retrieve the [user](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.user) that did the request. Just check its type (value of your ChoiceField field or actual type of your user it you chose to do it with subclasses) and serve the appropriate page according to this.

It should work.